How to add a dot icon over the selected icon in bottom nav bar in jetpack compose?

I want to add this dot icon over the selected tab icon in the bottom nav bar. I don't want to use images for this. I am using Jetpack Compose.
That design which is outside the bottom nav bar is required.
How can I achieve this in jetpack composition? Also if I want to fill the icon with custom color how can I accomplish that?
Here is my code:
@Composable
fun BottomBar(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    var navNum by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }

    Row(
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .clip(RoundedCornerShape(topStart = 30.dp, topEnd = 30.dp))
            .background(CardColor)
            .padding(vertical = 15.dp, horizontal = 15.dp),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
    ) {
        Row(verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically) {
            if (navNum == 0) {
                IconButton(onClick = { /*TODO*/ }) {
                    Icon(
                        painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.home_filled),
                        contentDescription = "home",
                        tint = SecondaryColor,
                        modifier = Modifier.size(25.dp),
                    )
                }
            } else {
                IconButton(onClick = { navNum = 0 }) {
                    Icon(
                        painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.home_light),
                        contentDescription = "home",
                        tint = ThinTextColor,
                        modifier = Modifier.size(25.dp),
                    )
                }
            }

            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(8.dp))

            if (navNum == 1) {
                IconButton(onClick = { /*TODO*/ }) {
                    Icon(
                        painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.calendar_filled),
                        contentDescription = "home",
                        tint = SecondaryColor,
                        modifier = Modifier.size(25.dp)
                    )
                }
            } else {
                IconButton(onClick = { navNum = 1 }) {
                    Icon(
                        painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.calendar_light),
                        contentDescription = "home",
                        tint = ThinTextColor,
                        modifier = Modifier.size(25.dp),
                    )
                }
            }
        }

        Row(verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically) {
            if (navNum == 2) {
                IconButton(onClick = { /*TODO*/ }) {
                    Icon(
                        painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.message_filled),
                        contentDescription = "home",
                        tint = SecondaryColor,
                        modifier = Modifier.size(25.dp),
                    )
                }
            } else {
                IconButton(onClick = { navNum = 2 }) {
                    Icon(
                        painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.message_light),
                        contentDescription = "home",
                        tint = ThinTextColor,
                        modifier = Modifier.size(25.dp),
                    )
                }
            }

            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(8.dp))

            if (navNum == 3) {
                IconButton(onClick = { /*TODO*/ }) {
                    Icon(
                        painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.user_filled),
                        contentDescription = "home",
                        tint = SecondaryColor,
                        modifier = Modifier.size(25.dp),
                    )
                }
            } else {
                IconButton(onClick = { navNum = 3 }) {
                    Icon(
                        painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.user_light),
                        contentDescription = "home",
                        tint = ThinTextColor,
                        modifier = Modifier.size(25.dp),
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


To achieve this in compose, you can use NavigationBar for material 3 or BottomNavigation for material 2. In my example, i'll be using material 3 and the NavigationBar.
To replicate the design with a dot over the selected item, we need to:
Create a custom shape for the bottom navigation item, which includes a curved border.
Use drawWithContent to add the dot above the selected icon.
First, we need to define a custom shape using a cubic bezier curve. This shape will give the selected tab that curved look:
val CurvedShape = remember {
    GenericShape { size, _ ->
        val width = size.width
        val height = size.height

        // Move to the top left corner
        moveTo(0f, 0f)
        lineTo(width - width / 7f, 0f)

        val start = Offset(width - width / 7f, height / 3.5f) // start pos of the curve
        val center = Offset(width, height/2f) // center pos of the curve
        val end = Offset(width - width / 7f, height - height / 3.5f) // end pos of the curve

        val controlDistance = 20 // length of control points of the bezier curve

        val c1 = Offset(start.x, start.y + controlDistance) // control points of the bezier curve
        val c2 = Offset(center.x, center.y - controlDistance)
        val c3 = Offset(center.x, center.y + controlDistance)
        val c4 = Offset(end.x, end.y - controlDistance)

        lineTo(start.x, start.y)

        cubicTo(
            x1 = c1.x,
            y1 = c1.y,
            x2 = c2.x,
            y2 = c2.y,
            x3 = center.x,
            y3 = center.y
        )
        cubicTo(
            x1 = c3.x,
            y1 = c3.y,
            x2 = c4.x,
            y2 = c4.y,
            x3 = end.x,
            y3 = end.y
        )

        lineTo(width - width / 7f, height)
        lineTo(0f, height)
    }
}

Now, you can conditionally apply this CurvedShape when the item is selected, and use drawWithContent to draw the dot above the selected icon.
modifier = Modifier
    .background(
        color = backgroundColor,
        shape = if (selectedIndex == 0) CurvedShape else RectangleShape
    )
    .then(
        if (selectedIndex == 0) {
            Modifier.drawWithContent {
                val radius = dotRadius.toPx()

                drawContent()
                drawCircle(
                    color = selectedIconColor,
                    radius = radius,
                    center = Offset(size.width - 3 * radius / 2, size.height / 2)
                )
            }
        } else {
            Modifier
        }
    )

You can easily change the colors of the selected and unselected icon using this:
colors = NavigationBarItemDefaults.colors().copy(
    selectedIconColor = selectedIconColor,
    unselectedIconColor = unselectedIconColor,
    selectedIndicatorColor = backgroundColor
)

Here’s the complete example:
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContent {
            Scaffold(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                bottomBar = { BottomBar() },
            ) { innerPadding ->
                // Your content goes here
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun BottomBar(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {

    var selectedIndex by remember { mutableIntStateOf(0) }

    val CurvedShape = remember {
        GenericShape { size, _ ->
            val width = size.width
            val height = size.height

            // Move to the top left corner
            moveTo(0f, 0f)
            lineTo(width - width / 7f, 0f)

            val start = Offset(width - width / 7f, height / 3.5f) // start pos of the curve
            val center = Offset(width, height/2f) // center pos of the curve
            val end = Offset(width - width / 7f, height - height / 3.5f) // end pos of the curve

            val controlDistance = 20 // length of control points of the bezier curve

            val c1 = Offset(start.x, start.y + controlDistance) // control points of the bezier curve
            val c2 = Offset(center.x, center.y - controlDistance)
            val c3 = Offset(center.x, center.y + controlDistance)
            val c4 = Offset(end.x, end.y - controlDistance)

            lineTo(start.x, start.y)

            cubicTo(
                x1 = c1.x,
                y1 = c1.y,
                x2 = c2.x,
                y2 = c2.y,
                x3 = center.x,
                y3 = center.y
            )
            cubicTo(
                x1 = c3.x,
                y1 = c3.y,
                x2 = c4.x,
                y2 = c4.y,
                x3 = end.x,
                y3 = end.y
            )

            lineTo(width - width / 7f, height)
            lineTo(0f, height)
        }
    }

    val backgroundColor = Color.LightGray
    val selectedIconColor = Color.Red
    val unselectedIconColor = Color.Black

    val dotRadius = 5.dp


    NavigationBar(
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxWidth(),
        tonalElevation = 2.dp
    ) {

        NavigationBarItem(
            icon = {
                Icon(
                    imageVector = Icons.Filled.Home,
                    contentDescription = null,
                )
            },
            label = null,
            selected = selectedIndex == 0,
            onClick = {
                selectedIndex = 0
            },
            modifier = Modifier
                .background(
                    color = backgroundColor,
                    shape = if (selectedIndex == 0) CurvedShape else RectangleShape
                )
                .then(
                    if (selectedIndex == 0) {
                        Modifier.drawWithContent {
                            val radius = dotRadius.toPx()

                            drawContent()
                            drawCircle(
                                color = selectedIconColor,
                                radius = radius,
                                center = Offset(size.width - 3 * radius / 2, size.height / 2)
                            )
                        }
                    } else {
                        Modifier
                    }
                ),
            colors = NavigationBarItemDefaults.colors().copy(
                selectedIconColor = selectedIconColor,
                unselectedIconColor = unselectedIconColor,
                selectedIndicatorColor = backgroundColor
            )
        )

        NavigationBarItem(
            icon = {
                Icon(
                    imageVector = Icons.Filled.Call,
                    contentDescription = null,
                )
            },
            label = null,
            selected = selectedIndex == 1,
            onClick = {
                selectedIndex = 1
            },
            modifier = Modifier
                .background(
                    color = backgroundColor,
                    shape = if (selectedIndex == 1) CurvedShape else RectangleShape
                )
                .then(
                    if (selectedIndex == 1) {
                        Modifier.drawWithContent {
                            val radius = dotRadius.toPx()

                            drawContent()
                            drawCircle(
                                color = selectedIconColor,
                                radius = radius,
                                center = Offset(size.width - 3 * radius / 2, size.height / 2)
                            )
                        }
                    } else {
                        Modifier
                    }
                ),
            colors = NavigationBarItemDefaults.colors().copy(
                selectedIconColor = selectedIconColor,
                unselectedIconColor = unselectedIconColor,
                selectedIndicatorColor = backgroundColor
            )
        )

        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))

        NavigationBarItem(
            icon = {
                Icon(
                    imageVector = Icons.Filled.ShoppingCart,
                    contentDescription = null,
                )
            },
            label = null,
            selected = selectedIndex == 2,
            onClick = {
                selectedIndex = 2
            },
            modifier = Modifier
                .background(
                    color = backgroundColor,
                    shape = if (selectedIndex == 2) CurvedShape else RectangleShape
                )
                .then(
                    if (selectedIndex == 2) {
                        Modifier.drawWithContent {
                            val radius = dotRadius.toPx()

                            drawContent()
                            drawCircle(
                                color = selectedIconColor,
                                radius = radius,
                                center = Offset(size.width - 3 * radius / 2, size.height / 2)
                            )
                        }
                    } else {
                        Modifier
                    }
                ),
            colors = NavigationBarItemDefaults.colors().copy(
                selectedIconColor = selectedIconColor,
                unselectedIconColor = unselectedIconColor,
                selectedIndicatorColor = backgroundColor
            )
        )

        NavigationBarItem(
            icon = {
                Icon(
                    imageVector = Icons.Filled.Menu,
                    contentDescription = null,
                )
            },
            label = null,
            selected = selectedIndex == 3,
            onClick = {
                selectedIndex = 3
            },
            modifier = Modifier
                .background(
                    color = backgroundColor,
                    shape = if (selectedIndex == 3) CurvedShape else RectangleShape
                )
                .then(
                    if (selectedIndex == 3) {
                        Modifier.drawWithContent {
                            val radius = dotRadius.toPx()

                            drawContent()
                            drawCircle(
                                color = selectedIconColor,
                                radius = radius,
                                center = Offset(size.width - 3 * radius / 2, size.height / 2)
                            )
                        }
                    } else {
                        Modifier
                    }
                ),
            colors = NavigationBarItemDefaults.colors().copy(
                selectedIconColor = selectedIconColor,
                unselectedIconColor = unselectedIconColor,
                selectedIndicatorColor = backgroundColor
            )
        )
    }
}

Demo:

